# Safe and sounder/soundier?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

Is it safe and sounder or safe and soundier?

Like we say "May God keep you safe and sounder/soundier"

What is correct way to say?

Comment: Neither; the idiom is simply "*safe and **sound***".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparative form of the adjective *sound* is *sounder*.  All (or almost all) one-syllable adjectives use *-er* in this way.

Perhaps I have just wished someone will be "safe and sound", but then I wish a second person will be "safer and sounder".  I could go on and wish a third person will be "safest and soundest".